# Migrate from blockchain.info to bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info

I currently have my wallet with blockchain.info.

Is there any way that I can import this address into the bitcoin-qt client?

Comment: Its best you don't reuse addresses anyway so there is no harm in just moving your coins across to a new wallet.

Comment: Plus, you can be sure that actually nobody grabbed the private key of that address from your browser or from Blockchain.info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Login to your blockchain.info wallet
2. Select **Import/Export**
3. Select **Export Unencrypted**
4. Select **Bitcoin-Qt Format** from the drop-down list

You'll then see information that look like this:

`"priv":"5KJvsngHeMpm884wtkJNzQGaCErckhHJBGFsvd3VyK5qMZXj3hS"`

Ignore the other information, what you're looking for are your private keys that look like this: `5KJvsngHeMpm884wtkJNzQGaCErckhHJBGFsvd3VyK5qMZXj3hS`

Then just follow [Rick's instructions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-qt-on-a-mac/5944#5944) to import each of your private keys into the Bitcoin-Qt client:

> 1. Run Bitcoin-QT
> 2. Select **Help** (to the right of Settings)
> 3. Select **Debug Window**
> 4. Select **Console**
> 5. Next to the > input box type `importprivkey <bitcoinprivkey>`
>
> Example: `importprivkey 5KJvsngHeMpm884wtkJNzQGaCErckhHJBGFsvd3VyK5qMZXj3hS`