# How do you sweep a paper wallet with Bitcoin-Qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, paper-wallet, import

Sweeping involves importing a private key, then sending it's entire balance to a new address in your wallet via a new transaction.  This would protect your paper wallet's bitcoins from being stolen if someone else ever had access to your paper wallet, or obtains access to your paper wallet in the future.

I'd love to know all the nitty-gritty steps involved with Bitcoin-Qt.

Answer (score 2):

1. Unlock your wallet
2. Run Import Command in Debug Window
3. Sweep to another key

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:How_to_import_private_keys_in_Bitcoin_Core_0.7%2B

Tools needed: camera in your PC + qr code reader.
But of course you can find the private key value with classical mathematics ;)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a feature that's supported or encouraged with Bitcoin Core.

Comment: The functionality certainly exists.

Comment: There is no sweep function in Bitcoin Core.

Comment: You can certainly send your entire balance to a new address. It can't watch for future incoming transactions on that address and automatically resend them somewhere else, but that doesn't seem to be the sense of "sweep" that the OP is asking for.

Comment: Doing it manually is not a function of the client. I can *say* that raw transactions let me make a transaction only spendable with a hash collision, but it is not a function of the client. You can approximate a private key sweep with a transaction.. but it's not a function of the client. See what I'm saying here? Bitcoin core does not have private key sweeping capability, it's not a function of the client.

Comment: I understood the question to be asking for the specific instructions on how to, in your words, "approximate" this feature. If I get a chance I will try to add an answer along those lines.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes that's what I'm looking for.  Instructions on [importing a private into Bitcoin Core already exist](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-qt), I'd like an augmented version with the commands that would send the private key's balance to a new address.