# Transfer wallet from Armory to Bitcoin-Qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, armory

I have a wallet with [Armory](https://bitcoinarmory.com/) which I'm not happy with and I'd like to manage my wallet with [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/download). Is there way to "transfer" the wallet between the clients? I'm currently running OSX 10.11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just send the money to your new wallet

Comment: That such an easy solution. Can't believe I didn't think of it...

Comment: But then you're paying pointless transaction fees.

Answer (score 6):

You can't transfer the wallet, per se, but you can transfer the private keys. Here's how to do it:

1. Run armory in offline mode (simply run `armory --offline`)
2. Click on your wallet and click "Backup This Wallet" and enter the password.
3. Select "Export Key Lists" and click the button at the bottom
4. Check "Private Key (Plain Base58)" from the checklist and nothing else.
5. Select "Omit spaces in key data", as these may cause an "Invalid private key encoding" during import
6. Take each private key listed in the window and import them into bitcoin by using this command: `bitcoin-cli importprivkey <privkey>`

Just out of curiosity, what aren't you happy about with Armory? I ask because I'm an Armory developer.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm just gonna transfer the money. I'm not happy with Armory for the following reasons: 1) dependency on Bitcoin-Qt 2) Poor UX (eg: after sending money I have to wait for two screen changes and a potential popup before the transaction is done and none of this is messaged to the user) 3) Constant crashes 4) Bad update system (I was repeatedly prompted to update to 93 when it still wasn't available)

Comment: Sorry about that. FYI, there will be changes for all those things in the future.

Comment: No need to apologize :) you're providing software for free.

Comment: As bitcoin-cli might not be installed/available to import the private keys, you may also use the command tool, build into Bitcoin-qt by default (Help > Debug Window > Console), see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5944/45378