# How can I withdraw Litecoin from a paperwallet?

Tags: litecoin, paper-wallet

How can I withdraw my Litecoin from a paperwallet?

I have tried to use blockchain.info but it seems like it is only bitcoin that I can withdraw with that.

I used the bitcoinpaperwallet.com webpage to make the wallet.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Both blockchain.info and bitcoinpaperwallet.com are for Bitcoin, you need a Litecoin wallet and then import your private key to that.

The most reliable way to have a Litecoin wallet is to download and run the official [Litecoin Core client](https://litecoin.org/#download), although you can use web based wallets as well but as I have no experience using them I can only give you a [search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=online%20litecoin%20wallet).

With Litecoin Core you will have full ownership over your wallet and you will not be depending on the service availability of the website, but this also means you will need to backup your wallet as the wallet.dat will contain your coins.

Importing a private key in Litecoin Core is the same as with Bitcoin (based on [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-qt)):

- click on 'help' in the menu bar (top right)
- click on 'debug window'
- select the 'console' tab type: `walletpassphrase "passphrase here" 600` (only if you set up a passphrase to protect your wallet earlier (you should!))
- type `importprivkey [private key here]`

You will have to wait the synchronization to finish to see your balance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with transferring an encrypted paper Litecoin wallet to. I tried first Exodus and after typing the private key manually I could not make it work, Then I tried Litecoin core and using the debug screen (very primitive} typing the keys again I could not make it work. Then I read a suggestion to use Loaf Wallet on my phone and I scanned the litecoin and picked them up. I think I have to be carefull that I move them out because I read this method was not safe. Here is the step by step:
 Loafwallet
Perhaps the easiest method to spend your Litecoin is through loafwallet, the mobile wallet developed by the Litecoin Foundation.

Go to Menu-> Settings-> Start/Recover Another Wallet
Scan the QR code of your private key
Then you're done!
You can either keep your LTC there, or send it to another LTC wallet.  Depending on how you generated your LTC, it may be important to spend the entire balance in your paper wallet.

For example, if you generated the QR codes yourself from a LTC wallet then you should most definitely spend the entire balance in your address.  The reason for this is that wallets typically create "Change Addresses" for your LTC to get sent to if you partially spend your balance.  Because you most likely don't have access to the wallet you used to generate your paper wallet from, the remaining LTC will be lost because you don't have access to the change addresses.

However if you created your paper wallet from liteaddress, this isn't an issue.

From: https://theliteschool.com/lsc/how-to-create-and-spend-a-paper-wallet

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a wallet on paper wallets like [LitAddress](https://liteaddress.org/) and [LitecoinPaperWallet](https://litecoinpaperwallet.com/) then you have got your private key as well.

You can use your private keys to withdraw or send your LTC to any LTC address.

Litecoins official wallet allows accessing wallet using paper wallet (I mean Private Key).

Answer (score -2):

Go onto a credible website download the HTML then turn off your internet ensure the code is fine.

If browser has privacy turn it on then make your paper wallet print it out then put in fake data as well then clear you browser cache. Recommend you use a fresh browser on USB stick or something as well during this.

Next turn on your internet if you haven't already downloaded some wallet, do so.  Either Litecoin client or some credible wallet if not litecoin client be aware where you download also note their fees, privacy policy, credibility and EULA.

Next search how to import private keys into your specific wallet
for LiteCoin -- help - Debug
importprivkey "litecoinprivkey" ( "label" ) ( rescan )
importpubkey "pubkey" ( "label" rescan )

If your using going to use it continuously after you imported private key should be good to go. If it has extra security you should use it such as pin numbers, 2 part verification. If it's not large amounts at least a pin along with encryption. Your ready to use it for donating to charity or buying things know your countries laws or policy before doing so.

if you only want to put coins into your paper wallet and not spend them you should need only to generate a temporary software wallet put money in it then send it to your public address for your paper wallet.  So your paper wallet private key is never loaded into the wallet.

Comment: There are two downvotes, but no explanation as to why. I think the answer shows a good way of using paperwallet to fill a wallet, and takes security considerations into account.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are because it doesn't clearly answer OP's question.