# How can I recover dogecoins sent to a Bitcoin address?

Tags: paper-wallet, dogecoin, lost-transactions

I had transferred my Poloniex dogecoin cryptocurrency and accidentally sent it to a Bitcoin paperwallet using walletgenerator.net. It did go somewhere but do not know where.
Is there someone to contact for missing cryptos? I thought the Dogecoin address is different than the bitcoin and would not transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the address format is different (the prefix part) the transaction is valid so there will be a transaction on Dogecoin blockchain to the address.

I found a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/4846l7/yeah_you_can_send_btc_to_an_ltc_address_i_did_crap/) where they suggest to save your private key in the Bitcoin client and import it to your Dogecoin client, although it is not certain this will work, I think this is your best chance, as transactions are irreversible by design.

In the original Bitcoin Core client you export in the debug window (based on [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/how-can-i-export-the-private-key-for-an-address-from-the-satoshi-client) and [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-qt)):

- click on 'help' in the menu bar (top right)
- click on 'debug window'
- select the 'console' tab type: `walletpassphrase "passphrase here" 600`
- type: `dumpprivkey [address here]`

Then to import navigate to the same window in Dogecoin client and

- type `importprivkey [private key here]`