# How do I import a wallet into Bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, message-signing, private-key-import, import, wallet-import

I have the public address, and the private key of a BTC wallet. How can I import this into bitcoin core so that I can use it to sign messages?

I need to be able to sign a message to show that I possess the private keys for an account.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-core

Comment: what is YourLongPassphrase in that answer?

Comment: its a password you set up for bitcoin core wallet. if you don't have one (which is highly unrecommended) you should skip this command

Comment: It seems I have lost the passphrase. Is there any way to reset bitcoin core, or do i need to do a full reinstall? I have no funds on bitcoin core currently so have no problem resetting it all.  Thanks for your help, zergatul.

Comment: I am not sure, you can try to delete wallet.dat file

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just doing a reinstall. It was simpler than I expected. And for posterity, when I went to "change passphrase" I just put in a new passphrase as both the old and new passphrase and it worked. I Was then able to use the console to import the priivate key. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Answer was given for a similar question as commented by Zergatul here. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-core

Comment: Hi John, thanks, I've closed your question as a duplicate of that one, so that people who find your question will find Zergatul's answer.