# bitcoin-qt import private key doesn't seem to work

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key-import

I follow [this wiki guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:How_to_import_private_keys_in_Bitcoin_Core_0.7%2B) and [this thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-core). After executing the command `importprivkey mylongprivatekey` in the Console, I see a popup window saying

```
[MyWallet] Rescanning...
```

and that takes couple of hours to finish. When it's done, I do not see `Address Book` show up next to `Transactions` as in the wiki page.

I thought one issue may be that the wallet get locked after the 10 minutes allowance. But I tried longer time, like 4 hours. Same issue.

I'm using bitcoin-0.20.0.

This is what I expect to see,
[image]

This is what I see after it finishes rescanning,
[image]

Comment: If you issue the `getaddressinfo <address>` command (with `<address>` replaced by the address that you had hoped to get the key imported for, what do you get?

Comment: @PieterWuille You mean issuing the command in the Console? I won't be able to try it until it stops rescanning....

Comment: Did you provide a label? Without label I don't think it'll show up in the address book. The RPC I mentioned will tell you whether it was properly imported.

Comment: @PieterWuille Yeap. Only complication is this. Because this didn't work the first time, I tried importing the same private key couple of times using either QT or the command line `bitcoin-cli`. Not sure if it might have confused the app

Comment: @PieterWuille It just finished and I did `getaddressinfo MyAddr` it shows the correct label.

Comment: @PieterWuille So, the private key has been imported successfully. Question then is why QT user interface doesn't show the `Address Book` button. And how do I send bitcoin out of this address, if it has balance (this particular one does not).

Comment: Oh that's just because the UI has been changed a lot. That documentation you're looking at is for version 0.7 (which was released in 2012). You don't need to do anything; if it's imported it'll work. If you had received coins on that address (or will receive), it'll show up in your balance, and be spendable.

Comment: @PieterWuille Then, is there any way to list all the addresses I've imported into this wallet?

Comment: It should be on the receive tab.

Comment: @PieterWuille In `Receive` tab, I don't see my imported address. I see a button `Create new receiving address` though. But that creates a new address.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know. I don't work on the GUI.

Comment: @PieterWuille Is there any command(s) on command line `bitcoin-cli` to show my addresses?