# Import WIF key for P2PKH into Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, output-script-descriptors, wallet-import-format

Can someone create a step by step, how to import a legacy P2PKH WIF key on testnet (let's say `cSTHGbKgKLCGDRRn5AgtS7L4KHkqmdBau4nsEw8ckAzXV784bgeR`) into Bitcoin Core 25.1 descriptor wallet using the Debug Console?

Comment: Does any of those answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/108392/101498, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/108392/101498, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/118130/101498.

Comment: thanks.. but most solutions are so complicated.. I was hoping that there was a simple 2-3 step process

Comment: Added an answer, you've got a step by step guide in the last link. You simply need to use `pkh()` instead of `pk()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah.. so let me make the step by step

1. getdescriptorinfo "pkh(cSTHGbKgKLCGDRRn5AgtS7L4KHkqmdBau4nsEw8ckAzXV784bgeR)"

result:

```
{
  "descriptor": "pkh(030264ff3c978d2845efd78ff3092650ff80e49a95bebe2fe2f0e9328f72e31799)#kfn7yc4w",
  "checksum": "h9ya7gkd",
  "isrange": false,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": true
}
```

important info is `"checksum": "h9ya7gkd"`

2. importdescriptors '[{"desc":"pkh(cSTHGbKgKLCGDRRn5AgtS7L4KHkqmdBau4nsEw8ckAzXV784bgeR)#h9ya7gkd","timestamp":"now"}]'

At this point I can see my address under `receiving addresses`

3. getaddressinfo mv9u2iuhXL86Y4JKHazEYvAzAXvbt5bwwo

result

```
{
  "address": "mv9u2iuhXL86Y4JKHazEYvAzAXvbt5bwwo",
  "scriptPubKey": "76a914a08e6d3854c35052dd64757f423c1bf91326c5b888ac",
  "ismine": true,
  "solvable": true,
  "desc": "pkh([a08e6d38]030264ff3c978d2845efd78ff3092650ff80e49a95bebe2fe2f0e9328f72e31799)#ywkyykha",
  "parent_desc": "pkh(030264ff3c978d2845efd78ff3092650ff80e49a95bebe2fe2f0e9328f72e31799)#kfn7yc4w",
  "iswatchonly": false,
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": false,
  "pubkey": "030264ff3c978d2845efd78ff3092650ff80e49a95bebe2fe2f0e9328f72e31799",
  "iscompressed": true,
  "ischange": false,
  "timestamp": 1706106032,
  "hdkeypath": "m",
  "hdseedid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "hdmasterfingerprint": "a08e6d38",
  "labels": [
    ""
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/118130/101498) contains a step-by-step guide to import a testnet WIF private key under a `pk()` (for P2PK) descriptor on a Bitcoin Core wallet using the command line. You can use the same commands in a Bitcoin Core GUI Debug Console. For P2PKH, you simply need to substitute `pk()` for `pkh()`.

Comment: ah.. so let me make the step by step

Comment: @MichelvanKessel: Self-answers are encouraged, so please post it as an answer here!