# Extracting forkcoins from legacy multisig Copay wallet

Tags: multi-signature, wallet-recovery, copay, cross-chain-recovery

In 2017, we made an m-out-of-n multisignature wallet in the Copay app. After this time, several forks have arisen. Bitpay, the successor of Copay, does have built in support for Bitcoin Cash (BCH), but not for some other forks that are still of value, like Bitcoin Gold (BTG), Bitcoin SV (BSV) and eCash (XEC).

My question is: what is the best way to extract these forkcoins out of the wallet? A small subtlety here is that we do not have all the private keys any longer, but we do have enough private keys to sign any transaction (i.e., at least m of them).

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, if you can extract the private keys from a wallet, then these private keys can be imported in to the native wallet/node app of the fork coins you are interested in.

Private keys are the "spending keys" matching public keys or "addresses"; with these keys it's possible to spend the funds in an address.

Copay is apparently an open-source project, so it should be possible to transfer private keys to fork coin's native app.

I found this link towards that aim: https://github.com/OmniLayer/omniwallet/wiki/Finding-and-Exporting-your-private-key-from-Bitpay-Copay

To use your private keys from Copay with the native node/wallet of Bitcoin Gold (BTG), Bitcoin SV (BSV) and eCash (XEC), you will want to get these projects' native wallet/node apps and first run them until they have downloaded their complete, distinct post-fork blockchains.

Then you may import the private keys into each of the wallet files  of these coins (usually *wallet.dat*). Re-starting the nodes will trigger a rescan of the blockchains for transactions that pertain to the addresses in their wallets, and render your pre-fork bitcoin coins visible in the post-fork wallets of the fork coins.

Here is a link for how to import keys into a wallet (bitcoin in this example) : [How do I import a private key into Bitcoin-Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-core)

Comment: Warning: move all of your BTC out of the wallets that you will be handling, **before** you import those wallet's privkeys into some other (potentially malicious) node/wallet software.