# import private key into bitcoincore - getting error

Tags: private-key-import

I am a total dummy/layperson and cannot figure out how to import my private key into bitcoincore v23. I keep getting the error "this type of wallet does not support this command" when typing in "importprivkey" and then pasteing my private key.

Is there anyone that can talk to me about this like I am 5?!

Thank you kindly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a private key be imported to a descriptor wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113846/how-can-a-private-key-be-imported-to-a-descriptor-wallet)

Answer (score 1):

`importprivkey` can only be used with legacy wallets, you're apparently using a descriptor wallet. Simply create a new wallet with "Descriptor Wallet" unchecked and you'll be able to import the private key.

Comment: Thank you! Now I got an error that says Rescan is disabled when blocks are pruned. I created my private key using bitaddress.org. Should I have used something different? THANK YOU!

Comment: A private key generated using a website is not very secure. If you can, you should just generate keys with the wallet you use.

Comment: Thank you...I really don't know what I am doing. My exhusband created an offline wallet of sorts for me, but is not giving me all the information I need to move it online, only bits and pieces. He told me to use bitaddress.org to put in my password and then make a private key. Then to take the private key to bitcoin core to move it to a place that makes it accessible to me. I'm lost. But thank you so much for your time!

Comment: When choosing  `File > Create Wallet` I don't see the `Descriptor Wallet` checkbox.  Using Bitcoin Core 26.0.0.   Any ideas how to create a new Legacy wallet that I can then import private keys into?