# P2SH-P2WSH-P2PKH and P2SH-P2WPKH

Tags: script, segregated-witness

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using P2WSH-wrapped P2PKH instead of  P2WPKH?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using P2SH-wrapped P2WSH-wrapped P2PKH instead of P2SH-wrapped P2WPKH?

Comment: I’m kinda curious actually, in what context would this question even come up?

Comment: @Murch [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113846/how-can-a-private-key-be-imported-to-a-descriptor-wallet/113853#comment132004_113854) or [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64396069#64396069). :D

Comment: I would guess that Pieter meant that as an absurd example. No idea why anyone would actually do it.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t think of any advantages for either of those constructions. As far as I can tell they simply use more weight, are more complicated, and highly fingerprintable because they would be extremely uncommon. I can’t think of any reason for anyone to do either, except “because they can”.