# How would I generate a valid vanity address for destroying coins?

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen, destroy-bitcoins

I want to generate very long vanity addresses, with the relaxed constraint that I don't need the corresponding private key, they only need to be valid Bitcoin addresses. How would I do this?

Example:

```
Input Prefix: 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Output: 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXUW9j3f3
```

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/how-can-i-generate-a-vanity-bitcoin-address?rq=1

Comment: Here's one: 1AnyCoinsSentHereAreDestroyedKPAHm

Comment: n00b question, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this manually using the hex/base58check converter (such as the converter on brainwallet.org)

1. Remove the starting `1` and convert from base58 `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` to hex: `25c7415deb828c49ccb799c452ae17589bca1af2` (make sure result is 24 bytes)
2. Remove last 4 bytes to get a 20-byte hash:
   `25c7415deb828c49ccb799c452ae17589bca1af2` -> `25c7415deb828c49ccb799c452ae1758`
3. Convert from hex `25c7415deb828c49ccb799c452ae1758` to base58check: `1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYDgWVE`

Final result is valid `1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYDgWVE`

Comment: this example does not work here. Even when I check the bitcoin address 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYDgWVE on block explorer it says "invalid address". Can someone explain please step-by-step (and which online converter to use) for creating a vanity bitcoin address without the need to know the private key. It should just act as a proof-of-burn address. Any help appreciated

Comment: Hi @user882786, you're commenting and asking for clarification on a question from 2014, you will probably have more success if you ask a new question.