# What is vanity address?

Tags: vanity-address

I saw lot of questions about vanity addresses, but not sure what is vanity address. Could someone please explain?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the same thing as a [vanity plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_plate) which are used for cars. That is: An address which you choose yourself (or at least part of it). For example the address of Bitcoin24 is 1BTC24yVKQdQNAa4vX71xLUC5A8Za7Rr71 (watch the first six characters!).

See this question [How can I generate a vanity Bitcoin address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/how-can-i-generate-a-vanity-bitcoin-address?rq=1)

Answer (score -4):

The first Google hit for `vanity address` for me is https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen.

> If you're tired of the random, cryptic addresses generated by regular bitcoin clients, you can use vanitygen to create a more personalized address.

Comment: 1. Having an easy-to-find answer is not a case for downvoting a question on SE. 2. A page explaining the technical details of using Vanitygen is not the same as answering the question "What is a vanity address?". 3. By giving this answer you've bumped the question, so by your approach, you've contributed to the waste of resources.

Comment: some people need to learn by asking a real person, i find your attitude to learner sucks and is counter productive to the adoption of bitcoin. + you make new people feel like they suck and are dumb. downvoted you